# setting row data on rowdatabound event

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I have a table `id="table_results_header"` which is inside a `ItemTemplate`.  Is it possible, using the `rowdatabound` event to call the instance of that table that occurs on each row of the encapsulating gridview so that I can manipulate the styles programatically?

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    however_you_get_to_the_table.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
}
```

I'm really curious to know if this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `FindControl`

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  ((Table)e.Row.FindControl("table_results_header")).BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was perfect.  Thanks.